# CMake Error "NumPy import failure" when compiling Boost.Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, cmake, anaconda

Here is what I installed as described [here](https://github.com/mitmul/ssai-cnn):

```
1. Python 3.5 (Anaconda3 2.4.3)
    Chainer 1.5.0.2
    Cython 0.23.4
    NumPy 1.10.1
    tqdm
2. OpenCV 3.0.0
3. lmdb 0.87
4. Boost 1.59.0
```

Next I want to compile and install Boost.NumPy. In the beginning, NumPy module could not be found. After some search, I found NumPy-related files in `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy` instead of something like `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`, etc. Therefore, in `/Boost.NumPy/CMakeList.txt`, I added this line:

```
set(NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS, /home/graphics/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages)
```

But NumPy still could not be found. An error occurred as I run `cmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$HOME/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.5m.so ../` to generate the makefile for Boost.NumPy. Here is the error:

```
graphics@gubuntu:~/usr/Boost.NumPy/build$ sudo cmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$HOME/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.5m.so ../
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.5 (found suitable version "3.5.1", minimum required is "3.5") 
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.5 (found version "3.5.1") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /home/graphics/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.5m.so
CMake Error at libs/numpy/cmake/FindNumPy.cmake:61 (message):
  NumPy import failure:

  Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I have tried to replace `NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS` with some other directories, but nothing works. What should I write to the `CMakelists.txt` to tell cmake where to find NumPy module and import it?

Thanks in advance!

---

Others files which might be needed to find out what goes wrong:

1. [CMakeLists.txt](http://example.haichaoyu.com/example/CMakeLists.txt) of Boost.NumPy.

Comment: Comma (`,`) is not needed in `set()` command. Also, instead of modification of 3d-party CMake scripts, it is preferred to set variables, described environment, in `cmake` call: `cmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=<...> -DNUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=<...> <source-dir>`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks, but it does not work after I run it as this: `sudo cmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$HOME/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.5m.so -DNUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=$HOME/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy ../`. what should I write?

Comment: Variable `NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS` sets directory for search **header files** (in C/C++ sources). It doesn't affect on python modules searching. You need to set [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) *environment* variable for make things work.

Answer (score 1):

Finally it works! But I don't know why...:(

What I did:

```
1.  I reinstalled numpy to /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (previously, I installed it to ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages)
1.1 I also added ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/include to $PYTHONPATH and $PATH
2.  I ran these commands in Python:
   >>>import numpy 
   And I found it returns no error!
3.  I removed previously compiled files in directory build, and rebuilt. Finally it worked
```

Hope these helps someone else.